# Can PHP interact with WCF web servives

Tags: c#, php, wcf

My company currently have web services written in WCF in C#, I have been asked to adjust my interface to interact with the web services, the interface is written in PHP/HTML. It will be running VIA IIS as well as the services.

Is this possible or do I need to tell me boss we need to go back to the drawing board

Comment: I believe it is possible, Google turns up some old articles.  However, it will be a little more work than if written in something like C#.  Writing the interface will probably still be less work than rewriting the application.

Answer (score 0):

WCF Services can be accessed by any other application that is built on any platform and using any programming language.Web services are interoperable.

Answer (score 0):

You can either expose a REST endpoint:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx

Or just put a ASP.Net Web API in front of your WCF service to act as a middle man:

http://www.asp.net/web-api

In php there are a number of ways of talking to a RESTful service, here is one library that can help:

http://phphttpclient.com/